# Writing how the advice turned out

Tags: discussion, answers

There are some SE sites, where an answer is obviously either correct or wrong (like math) and then there are some where there isnt a correct answer in principle (like codegolf) and some where the answer can't be really tested (like worldbuilding).

And then there are SE sites where people ask for advice what to do in certain situations (like Workplace, Interpersonal Skills, most of Academia and something in Money, Law, Travel a probably many others) where it is hard to judge how good an answer is, but the person who asked the question  probably tries to do what the accepted answer suggested.

Why isn't it a custom in these situations for the asker to write how the story turned out, as a feedback for the answerer and a prediction/verification for anyone trying similar approach?

Answer (score 11):

Contrary to what sites like The Workplace, Academia or Interpersonal Skills might look like to outsiders, **they are *not* sites for giving personal advice!** They are first and foremost Q&A archives in the spirit no different than Mathematics's or Stack Overflow's.

While the questions might be a little more personally *motivated* or the answers might be based more on personal *experience* than hard facts, on the bottom line **SE doesn't care the slightest about your personal life story**, more often than not it might even be a *hindrance* for properly answering the question (*and* objectively assessing the quality of the answers) if it's laden with too much of a "storyline". So I doubt coming back and telling "the end of the story" would be all too constructive.

You bring up the argument of assessing the correctness or appropriateness of answers this way, but even that is the wrong approach really (and might actually be actively harmful). We're supposed to **judge answers based on the backing they provide to *show us why* they're correct** (and yes, even on those sites answers very much need to be backed with support), not based on the things that happened to the asker. At the end of the day, the asker *still* has the accept button to show what *he* chose as the best solution. (And even on the more "hard" sites you could argue that acceptance really isn't of much worth over upvotes, upvotes based on the general quality of the answers, not incidental background info.)

Comment: There was a [post](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/how-to-encourage-askers-to-tell-the-end-of-the-story) linked in one of the now deleted comments under the question. Isn't it to a certain degree against your answer (from what I have seen, the consensus there is that while disclosing the end of the story shouldn't be mandatory, it is mostly beneficial)...

Comment: @Viki Stack Exchange's goal is to help future readers who have the same problem, not only the asker. While it might be beneficial for the asker to tell how the answers turn out, it may also give a biased opinion, just like [the answer acceptance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). (some accepted answers are worse than the most upvoted answers)